# Linking Error - No Write Permission

Tags: java, android, linker-errors

I have a problem with a project I am working on in Android Studio. The goal is to save a basic string into a .csv file then attach that file as an email attachment.

I cant write to the file, but I can share the file via FileProvider.getUriForFile.

I think the problem has something to do with these two linker error messages I get, the `streamsavvy-1` is concerning bc my package name is `com.team6.rifflegroup.streamsavvy`

```
11-13 16:20:39.775 10286-10286/com.team6.rifflegroup.streamsavvy E/linker: readlink('') failed: No such file or directory [fd=31]
```

11-13 16:20:39.775 10286-10286/com.team6.rifflegroup.streamsavvy E/linker: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/app/com.team6.rifflegroup.streamsavvy-1/oat/arm64/base.odex". Will use given name.

I build the file like this

```
File dataPath = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "xml");
File newData = new File(dataPath, FILE_NAME);
```

I have a `paths.xml` file within an xml directory under res that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="my_files"
        path="/"/>
</paths>
```

my write function looks like this

```
try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newData);
        writer.append(csv);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My Email intent looks like this

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.team6.rifflegroup.streamsavvy.FileProvider", newData);

    this.grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"myEmail@gmail.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "File Attached");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

I give permission in my manifest here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".dataLayout">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.team6.rifflegroup.streamsavvy.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

I feel like this is a problem with the way java builds its projects but I am not very familiar with the process. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

This is my first time posting here so I am so sorry if my post is out of context or improperly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Apologize for the long post. Figured it out.

had to declare the `.mkdirs()` call (not `.mkdir()`) after specifying the file.